# Why don't Scala primitives show up as type parameters in Java reflection?

Tags: scala, generics, reflection

Given the following case class:

```scala
case class Foo(
    bar: Int,
    baz: Boolean,
    qux: Option[Int],
    quux: Option[Boolean],
    quuux: Option[Integer]
)
```

I would expect the following:

```scala
for (f <- classOf[Foo].getDeclaredFields) {
    println(f.getGenericType)
}
```

to produce something like:

```
int
boolean
scala.Option<int>
scala.Option<boolean>
scala.Option<java.lang.Integer>
```

But instead, it produces:

```
int
boolean
scala.Option<java.lang.Object>
scala.Option<java.lang.Object>
scala.Option<java.lang.Integer>
```

Why do the primitives get erased from the generics, instead of getting treated as `java.lang.Integer.TYPE` and `java.lang.Boolean.TYPE`, as appears to happen with the plain fields?

And is there any way to retrieve the primitive type parameters from `classOf[Foo]`?

Comment: I don't recall the exact details right now, so I won't be answering, but if anyone wants a clue, it cannot be anything other than `Object` because, otherwise, it would cause signature incompatibility under some situations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scala thinks that the generic parameter for primitives is `scala.<Primitive>` e.g. `scala.Int`.  It doesn't store the type in the Java class file, though arguably it could.  (Or not; depends on whether there needs to be a distinction between `Int` and `java.lang.Integer`; under the hood the boxed form is `java.lang.Integer`, even if the compiler does a good job making you believe it is `Int`.)

Anyway, Scala has its own reflection capabilities which are in flux, but with 2.10 you can find the arguments of the `Option` types like so:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
typeTag[Foo].tpe.members.collect{
  case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m 
}.foreach(m => println(m.name + " " + m.typeSignature))
```

and you'll get something like

```
quuux => scala.Option[java.lang.Integer]
quux => scala.Option[scala.Boolean]
qux => scala.Option[scala.Int]
baz => scala.Boolean
bar => scala.Int
```